# ORA-12541: TNS:no listener error when trying to login through WSL to access OracleXE Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows

**System Details**

- WSL2 Ubuntu
- Oracle Instant Client (Inside of WSL)
- OracleXE (Inside of Windows)

I followed the instructions guide from the Oracle Documentation, added the path to the TNS_ADMIN, ORACLE_HOME, PATH, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it still returned this error message.

I copied the network/ADMIN folder to inside of the instantclient folder as an extra measure, but I think it might be unnecessary, if you need any more details I'll be happy to provide.

```
giovanni@P230820208_GIO:/$ sqlplus system/password@XE

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Feb 28 10:20:32 2024

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

This is the path I added to **~/.bashrc**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/gio/instantclient_11_2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/gio/instantclient_11_2
# export TNS_ADMIN=/home/gio/instantclient_11_2/network/ADMIN
```

This are the contents of **network/ADMIN folder**

```
giovanni@P230820208_GIO:~/instantclient_11_2/network/ADMIN$ ls
listener.ora  sample  sqlnet.ora  tnsnames.ora
```

This is content of the listener.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = P230820208_GIO)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your network listener service is running in Windows. Make sure both the network listener and data instance services are running. Why such an ancient version of Oracle? If you're using a recent version of Windows it probably isn't even certified to run on it.

Comment: @pmdba i used this version because its a requirement set by the company, and the listener service actually runs on windows surprisingly but on the WSL it still says no listener. I ran sqlplus on windows cmd and it pulled through with no problem, but when i tried it on WSL it says no listener.

Comment: I would question the requirement, if possible. 11g isn't supported, doesn't receive security patches, and won't run on most currently supported operating systems. It is literally a disaster waiting to happen. There's a very good chance it is too old to support WSL.